# Firebase error "auth/argument-error" when trying to sign in with Google/Facebook

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

Below is the relevant code. The error `auth/argument-error` is thrown when the method `signInWithPopup`  gets called:

```
import { AngularFireAuth } from "@angular/fire/compat/auth";
import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";

constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
  ) { }

async socialSignIn(providerName: "google" | "facebook") {
    const authProvider =
      providerName === "google"
        ? new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider()
        : new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    return this.afAuth.signInWithPopup(authProvider);
  }
```

The relevant dependencies:

```
"firebase": "9.6.9",
"@angular/fire": "7.3.0",
```

And I'm using Angular 13. Any idea why this is happening? The error is not very useful.

Answer (score 4):

it seems some references changed, you can import the class and instantiate instead of using firebase reference.

```
import { FacebookAuthProvider, GoogleAuthProvider } from '@angular/fire/auth';

new GoogleAuthProvider()
```

Comment: wow i spent 4 hours to get to this! man!!

Answer (score 0):

Reverting to `@angular/fire@7.2.1` has stopped this error from happening for me with Angular 13, firebase 9.8.1